# How to have different origin for each object when separating a mesh by loose parts?

Tags: mesh, objects, operator

When applying *separate by loose parts* to a mesh, I end up with many objects, as expected. But they all share the same origin. If I move one object, they all follow.

I've tried *unparenting*, but there is no Parent relation between them. It's the first time I encounter this. Is this expected behavior or a bug? Or Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you switch back to Object Mode, you can set the 'Origin to Geometry'.

With all the objects still selected, int the 3D view port, Go to :

'Object' -> 'Transform' -> 'Origin to Geometry'

Then the origin will be centered on the meshes physical center.

Comment: Thx. Life saver. :)

Comment: @dval Thanks for a tip. I've been always placing the origins individually for each separated object. Haven't got idea, that such helpful option exists :).

Comment: @PaulGonet You're welcome. Someone may correct me... I think since 2.6x most editing options can now be applied to multiple objects. This is a 'newer' feature that hasn't always been available.